# Check for call interruption - Android Lollipop

Tags: java, android, call, android-5.0-lollipop, interrupt

I am using the following code in `onPause` to check the call interruption in my app

```
//called inside ONPAUSE i.e. whenever my app is interrupted
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
String packageLaunched = runningTasks.get(0).baseActivity.getPackageName();

// see package name of app which interrupted my app 
if (!packageLaunched.contains("package.name.of.my.app")) {
    // do whatever when any other app interrups, as its on top.
}
```

The problem is,
packageLaunched used to change when call interrupted my app on previous versions of android.
But on android Lollipop call isn't in any running task :/

How can i track an incoming call from my android app?

Comment: This API was *never* meant for such usage

Comment: Yep, studied the documentation @ChrisStratton... Wont be using it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works on every version of android, including lollipop
Use this broadcast reciever

```
class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                // CALL_STATE_IDLE;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_IDLE",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                // CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // CALL_STATE_RINGING
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), incomingNumber,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_RINGING",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

and register it like this in onCreate

```
TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        TelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

And yes, please dont miss

Cheers! Your problems is solved ;)

Answer (score 1):

Register a `BroadCastReciever` for a Incoming call intent and do it in `onRecieveIntent` . Only a workaround though but will do the trick in all cases and all os versions.